# show this $\tan{x}\tan{y}\tan{z}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

in  an acute.$\Delta ABC$,if $x,y,z$ such$$\cos{A}=\cos{y}\sin{z},\cos{B}=\cos{z}\sin{x},\cos{C}=\cos{x}\sin{y}$$show that
$$\tan{x}\tan{y}\tan{z}=1$$or $$\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}=\cos{x}\cos{y}\cos{z}$$

I want use $$\cos^2{A}+\cos^2{B}+\cos^2{C}+2\cos{A}\cos{B}\cos{C}=1$$
so we have
$$\sum_{cyc}\cos^2{y}(1-\cos^2{x})+2\cos{x}\cos{y}\cos{z}\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}=1$$
then
$$\sum_{cyc}\cos^2{x}-\sum_{cyc}\cos^2{x}\cos^2{y}+2\cos{x}\cos{y}\cos{z}\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}=1$$
then I can't

Comment: Must $\Delta ABC$ be acute, like in [this question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h398482p2217397)?

Comment: Doesn't dividing both sides of $\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}=\cos{x}\cos{y}\cos{z}$ by $\cos{x}\cos{y}\cos{z}$ prove the equivalence, without any assumptions?

Comment: @GregMartin That is to be proven, the hypothesis is given in the first few lines $\cos A=\cos y \sin z..$

Comment: The edit cleared up the matter.

Comment: @TobyMak,Thanks give this important Information

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
\tan x\tan y\tan z=t
$$
then
$$
\sin x\sin y\sin z=t\cos x\cos y\cos z
$$
so we get
$$
\sum_{cyc}\cos^2x-\sum_{cyc}\cos^2x\cos^2y+2t\cos^2x\cos^2y\cos^2z=1
$$
then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (2t-1)\cos^2x\cos^2y\cos^2z \\\\[1ex]
=& 1-\sum_{cyc}\cos^2x+\sum_{cyc}\cos^2x\cos^2y-\cos^2x\cos^2y\cos^2z \\\\
=& \left(1-\cos^2x\right)\left(1-\cos^2y\right)\left(1-\cos^2z\right) \\\\[1ex]
=& \sin^2x\sin^2y\sin^2z
\end{aligned}
$$
therefore
$$
2t-1=\frac{\sin^2x\sin^2y\sin^2z}{\cos^2x\cos^2y\cos^2z}=\tan^2x\tan^2y\tan^2z=t^2
$$
so $$t=1$$